# Second div no wider than first div

Tags: html, css

I have this layout: https://postimg.org/image/74ioib3y7/

The rules of the game are:

1. The container must be at least 210px wide and 85px high
2. Row1 should be able to grow as wide as it needs to and wrap words only when the container is as big as its container
3. Row2 has to be as wide as Row1 => it should wrap words and not stretch the container when the content of Row2 is wider than the content of Row1

I have managed to do everything except 3.

EDIT: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mp3por/04g0c9sa/4/)

```
IGNORe THIS MUST HAVE IT TO PASTE JSFiddle
```

Please help

Comment: Do you have the code you tried ?

Comment: What have you already try? What about your source?

Comment: why not just set a container div around your rows with the preset width?

Comment: Why you hack `JSFiddle` paste w/o code limitation?

Comment: You forgot to set `container width`. Set `.container{max-width: 210px;/* It will not exit more than 210px width */ min-width: 100px; /* it will exit more than 100px width */}`.

Comment: Please remove downvotes of question. I have fixed everything :) It just took me a while to convert my code  into jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your request:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  background: aliceblue;
  min-width: 210px;
  min-height: 85px;
  position: relative;
}

.maxim {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
   background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <strong>12345620</strong>
        <span>description</span>   
    </header>
    <span class="maxim">
        Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  oposum
    </span>    
</div>    
        
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <strong>1234567890</strong>
        <span>description and more text is here also possible</span>   
    </header>
    <span class="maxim">
        Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  oposum
    </span>    
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you :) Great work with "possition:fixed" and then "possition:absolute"

Comment: Just for future reference - this otherwise perfect solution has a small problem - the lower part is not counted as part of the height of the containing div => if the text below takes more space than what is left after the 85 - upperDivHeight it will sit on overflow over a lower element.