# Custom widget to display value and information

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a widget that does looks like this: [image: widget]

The idea is that I have a value and it has some additional information. The problem is that this widget has to autosize to the width of the value, but not the width of the additional information. Additional information part is allowed to fill as much space as it wants downwards and wrap the content.

So far I have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932232/second-div-no-wider-than-first-div/41932896#41932896) however the problem with this one is that the additional info part does not count to the widget's height thus if it is longer it overflows on top of the thing underneath it or does not expand the containing div.

Please help

Comment: Please put some code that you have tried so far or create a fiddle. It will help in solving the issue. Thanks.

Comment: No javascript I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After considerable searching, I think the problem is with the `position:absolute`, and so far the recommendations I've read is to handle it via JS. I am not sure if that's acceptable to you, but I've been able to solve it here:

https://jsfiddle.net/anut12tp/5/

Basically, I've set the inner span as absolute, but on load I call the JS to set it's max width equal to it's parent and then change it's display to inline-block and position to relative.

Please have a look and let me know if this works for you. Thanks.

Comment: Hey man. Thank you for the answer. This works as expected. I have done tons of research as well and only found a way to do this with JS as well. This works ( for the small test suite i could think of ). I will mark it as an accepted answer since it does work and is the only solution so far in a day to allow for others to try and hopefully solve it with CSS only.

Comment: @mp3por Thanks for the response. I appreciate your consideration to select this as a accepted answer (please do click that tick :D). Although I do agree that you were looking for a pure CSS solution, for which I too am on the lookout!. And yeah, thanks a bunch for the up-vote :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this? `display: inline-block;` and `position:absolute;` on the parent and `position:absolute;` on the info element seems to do the trick.

```css
#wrapper{  
  display: inline-block;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
}
#header, #info{
  border:black 2px solid;
}
#info{
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">Value xyz</div>
  <div id="info">Info Info Info Info Info</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for trying. This solution has the same problem - if you look at the container div of the "wrapper" ( the body ) it is as high as the 'value' div and the 'info' part does not count. Thus if I had some thing beneath this widget it will just spill the info on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of what you [shared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932232/second-div-no-wider-than-first-div/41932896#41932896) in your post.

You may try this:

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: aliceblue;
  width: 200px;
}
.maxim {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
   background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <strong>12345620</strong>
        <span>description</span>   
    </header>
    <span class="maxim">
        Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum
    </span>    
</div>    

<div class="container">
    <header>
        <strong>1234567890</strong>
        <span>more text is here</span>   
    </header>
    <span class="maxim">
        Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  oposum
        Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  oposum
        Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum  oposum
    </span>    
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think OP wants a fixed width for the .container?

Comment: Hi man, Thank you for the answer. Fixing the width on the container results in that if the 'value' is wider than 200px it will wrap. My idea is to allow the 'value' to grow as much as it needs so that it's content stays on 1 line. The use case is value is a big numer ( with big font ) and the description is what this number is - which is usually much longer than the number. So I don't want to wrap the number.